# Pop up showing same content on all posts display.

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have created a blog template, to show a custom posts in a grid of 3 columns.

like this

```
            <ul class="grid effect-6" id="grid">
                    <?php
                        //WordPress loop for custom post type
                         $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=online_courses');
                          while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                    <li class="viewoc viewoc-tenth">

                        <img src="<?php echo $cfs->get('top_image_oc'); ?>" style="background-color: <?php echo $cfs->get('add_bg_color'); ?>; "/>

                        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                        <button class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-8">Find Out More..</button>
                    </li>

                <div class="md-modal md-effect-8" id="modal-8">
                    <div class="md-content">
                        <div>
                            <h1 style="color: #0D3D62;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;line-height:50px;font-size: 50px;"><?php echo $cfs->get('trainer_name'); ?></h1>
                            <h1 style="color: #0D3D62;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;line-height: 50px;font-size: 35px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                            <h1 style="color: #0D3D62;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:25px;line-height: 50px;font-size: 50px;"><?php echo $cfs->get('duration_of_training'); ?></h1>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <button style="margin-bottom:20px;float:right;">BOOK NOW</button>
                            <button class="md-close" style="">Close me!</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="md-overlay"></div><!-- the overlay element -->

                    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
            </ul>
```

inside < li > < /li > there is a button when clicked will show the md-content

But when i click the button on any post displayed, it shows the same content on all posts of the first displayed post.

I am using this pop tutorial for it
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/

Comment: Your code doesn't show where the `$cfs` object is defined. Does `the_title()` output the *same* or *different* values for each post in the loop?

Comment: Hi $cfs is a custom field created by using a plugin, Yes the title are showing different.

Comment: If the Titles are showing differently, then the loop is functioning properly. Your problem is with the `$cfs` object. Please add its relevant code to your question, or else we have no way to help resolve the problem.

Comment: even that is working properly. Its the content inside md-modal,which is showing same on all posts

Comment: Are both instances of `the_title()` outputting properly, or only the one outside the modal?

Comment: the first one inside the li it shows properly i.e different for each post ( original post title ), but what is in md-modal it shows same content for any post on pop up

Comment: you can see the image here. It shows correctly all posts with title and button. http://s22.postimg.org/4whgwopq9/Screen_Shot_2013_11_20_at_8_25_04_PM.png but when i click on find out more on any post it shows same content in pop up, which is actually the content of first post

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Comment: What does the modal show for each of those three posts? Can you add that screenshot as well?

Comment: here you go, it shows the same pop up content on all posts http://s2.postimg.org/j7t7ju4vt/Screen_Shot_2013_11_20_at_8_37_18_PM.png, which is actually the content of first post Core Cardio

Comment: Otherwise, can you help me suggest a pop up method to show post content on clicking a button.